# Accessing an external SQL database in iOS

Tags: ios, sql-server, xcode4, database-connection

I am writing an iOS application that needs to access data from an external SQL Server 2005 database. I already have a website that accesses the same data.

I usually access the SQL server database using .NET along with stored procedures for security reasons.
I need to populate an array that will itself populate another `TableViewController`.
As I'm fairly new to the whole iOS thing, kindly let me know how I can do this. If it's possible, please suggest the syntax or Google keywords for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend making a simple WCF .NET REST Service that queries your database and returns what you need.

I'm pretty sure your iOS app will not be able to connect to it directly.

Check out the following;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

The code project tutorial is very easy to follow. And you can download the project code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will want to make an API to access your database and you can access it through web requests. Essentially you will be performing web requests and respond from your site in json or xml where within your iOS client side code you can parse that and do what you need with it.